# getElementsByClassName select and usage in a for

Tags: javascript, html

I need to make that if all the select options (with the same class) in a page have the `value = 1`, the price must be hidden. I created this code:

```
var variazione = document.getElementsByClassName("select-addition");
var base = 0;
var lunghezza = 0;
for (var i = 0; i <= variazione.length; i++) {
  if (variazione[i].selectedIndex == "1") {
    base = base + 1;
  }
  lunghezza = lunghezza + 1;
}
if (base == lunghezza)
  document.getElementById("info-add-on").style.display = "none";
else 
  document.getElementById("info-add-on").style.display = "block";
```

but the console returns: Cannot read property `selectedIndex` of undefined. But if I manually specify the value of I it works (for example with variazione[1]).

Answer (score 2):

The problem I see here is that in the `for` loop you are iterating until `i <= length` instead of doing `i < length`. Remember that as indexing from 0, the elements are in the range [0, ..., n-1].

By using the less-equal inequality operator, your code will always access one more element than the number of elements found with `getElementByClassName` and hence, you will be accessing some property of a nonexistent (undefined) variable, producing your error.